# How can JVM map a variable name to its memory address?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.height = 100;
cat.name = "Tom";
```

I have these codes above. I know my question sounds silly but how can JVM lookup the addresses of the variable "height" and "name" to store values?

There is always a table mapping variable names and addresses of all class fields, on the "method area" of JVM and it just searchs on there. Is this explanation correct?

Generally, I don't even understand how a computer can recognize what memory address I am talking about just by looking at a variable name on my code.

Can anybody help me to understand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. You are asking for a comprehensive education in fundamental topics including computer architecture, compilers, language translation, virtual machines, and a lot more.  StackOverflow is not a tutorial or discussion site.  As to your question, by the time the JVM sees the code it looks NOTHING like the Java you typed in, it's been compiled to bytecode and all this has been taken care of in an internally consistent manner.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry, not even close.

Comment: That's a question as broad as the OP's.  StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: One: You are accessing the fields of the class directly and that is a poor practice. Two: We **can** find out. There is a tool called `javap` which comes with the JDK; it's a *class file disassembler* and can show you the byte code that your program uses. Three: I see a *Constant pool* containing *`Fieldref`(s)*. Four: The [`putfield` op-code](https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref-putfield.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch note the byte code doesn't specify how the object will be laid out at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the program is running, there is no variable names except for debugging purposes.  **The details of how the program runs depends on the JVM design** however for the OpenJDK / OracleJVM, compiles the byte code down to native code and in which case it is machine code which is really running the code. The variable "name" is assigned an offset in the object e.g. +16 from the start.

> how can JVM lookup the addresses of the variable "height" and "name" to store values?

The memory at object+16 is read (or written) as an address or a Compressed Oops. e.g. say you have a 32-bit JVM to keep things simple, there is a 4 byte value at 16 bytes after the start of the object, this is the address of the Object used as the String.

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
```

This creates a new object by allocating enough memory on the heap. Say it is 24 bytes long. At first the data is full of zero (except the header which records the type as a pointer for example)

The constructor of the class is called to initialise the memory just allocated.

```
cat.height = 100;
```

Say height is assigned the offset + 12 from the start of the object.  In this case the address of `cat` which is a number is added to 12, and the memory at this location is assigned the value 100 as a 4 byte store.

```
cat.name = "Tom";
```

Say name is assigned the offset +16 from the start of the object (and we are using 32-bit references)   In this case the address of `cat` which is a number is added to 16, and the memory at this location is assigned the value of the reference which points to a String "Tom" as a 4 byte store.

> There is always a table mapping variable names and addresses of all class fields, on the "method area" of JVM and it just searchs on there. Is this explanation correct?

Looking up a table each time is very expensive.  Instead the offsets of each field is written into the machine code (once it is compiled) and the addition of the offset takes no extra time for most CPUs.

> Generally, I don't even understand how a computer can recognize what memory address I am talking about just by looking at a variable name on my code.

The name is turned into a number which is the offset of the field from the start of the object.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that after loading .class file, JVM resolves all the symbolic references to direct references (since the code is in bytecode form) to execute it one by one. I understood the mechanism better now.

Comment: @Bonsaisteak it has to layout the object in an optimal/final manner from the start as changing the data structure after the JIT optimises the code is too expensive.